# Run Parameterized jUnit tests without using Annotation

Tags: java, automated-tests, junit4

I am running parameterized jUnit tests by using Annotation `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` on my Test class. However now I need to also run my test class using `PowerMockRunner` and therefore use annotation `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`. Obviously this is not possible as only one `@RunWith` annotation is allowed.

How can I implement a parameterized test without using the annotation `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can bootstrap PowerMock using a JUnit Rule, so you no longer need the RunWith for that.

https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule

Comment: Many thanks, that works in my case... Anyway I am still looking for a solution which will let me leave out the @RunWith(Parameterized.class) annotation.